# Error trying to get Elmah to manually log messages

Tags: c#, elmah.mvc

I'm using ELMAH in my MVC4 project. I want to manually log messages. According to other SO questions on this subject I do this...

```
using Elmah;
```

and..

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
    new Exception("Hello I am testing Elmah", new NotSupportedException()));
```

But on my elmah.axd page (which displays all the logs) it says in the summary...

```
0   NotSupported    Specified method is not supported.
```

I was hopeing it would display my message. Can some one tell me if this is the way it is supposed to work, or am I doing it wrong and my log is causing an exception.

(Please keep answers simple as I'm new to c#)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Although it seems when it come from the Web Context it shows the message as you are hoping. It would seem if only a message is present it will show it.